# How to correctly display composed Unicode text in Java on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, unicode, fonts

I am having problems displaying Thai and Burmese characters with the accent/modifier correctly composed on to the main letter.

In the following example program the two sequences \u100a\u103a and \u0e27\u0e31 should each be rendered as a single glyph but on the Mac they appear decomposed into two characters.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test
{
    public static final String TEXT = "\u100a\u103a \u0e27\u0e31";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name")+" "+System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name")+" "+System.getProperty("os.version")+" "+System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        System.out.println("TEXT is "+TEXT);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title "+TEXT);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label "+TEXT);
        JTextField text = new JTextField("Text "+TEXT);
        text.setEditable(false);
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField("Text "+TEXT);
        text2.setFont(new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        text2.setEditable(false);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.getContentPane().add(text);
        f.getContentPane().add(text2);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The resulting output is

[image: Output of font test]

Interestingly, if I set the font to a monospaced font or to ArialUnicodeMS the Thai character is now displayed as a single glyph, but the Burmese character is still displayed as two. Both are displayed correctly in the window title and the Terminal window so I know Mac OS X itself has the correct fonts and knows how to render them.

How can I get them to display correctly in my Java app?